# A question about an interesting integration

Tags: real-analysis

It is easy to proof
$$\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\prod_{i,j=1}^n(x_i-y_j)dx_1\cdots dx_ndy_1\cdots dy_n=0$$
as $n$ is odd.

How to proof
$$\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\prod_{i,j=1}^n(x_i-y_j)dx_1\cdots dx_ndy_1\cdots dy_n\neq 0$$
as $n$ is even?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** assume, for clarity, that $n=2$, and our variables are $x,X,y,Y$. When expanding $(x-y)(x-Y)(X-y)(X-Y)$ we get many monomials with degree $2n$, having sign $+1$ if the number of $(y,Y)$ terms is even, $-1$ otherwise. Consider what happens when we integrate a single monomial, say $x^1 X^1 y^2$:
$$ \int_{(0,1)^{2n}} x^1 X^1 y^2\,d\mu = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3},$$
by Fubini's theorem. Let $\nu_2$ the usual $2$-adic height, for which $\nu_2(6)=1,\nu_2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=0,$ $\nu_2\left(\frac{3}{40}\right)=-3$. Among the integrals given by the single monomials, the integral
$$ \int_{(0,1)^{2n}} xXyY\,d\mu = \frac{1}{2^\color{blue}{4}} $$
is the only one with $2$-adic height $\color{blue}{-4}$. It follows that the sum of the contributes given by all the monomials cannot be zero.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio: Thank you very much for your help! I am unfamiliar with the concept 2-adic height. Would you please explain your answer more detailedly? By the way, is there any context of the integration in my question?

Comment: @user173856: You are integrating a resultant. You may see the $2-adic$ height as the power of $2$ that appears in the factorization of a rational number (here, negative exponents are allowed). The key fact is that $\nu_2(a)<\nu_2(b)$ implies $\nu_2(a+b)=\nu_2(a)$, so if we find a sum of rational numbers in which a single term has a very low $2$-adic height, such a sum cannot be zero.